# HSQLDB text search performance

Tags: sql, performance, hsqldb

I have poor performance when running a simple search (~20-30s):

```
select Text from Library where REGEXP_MATCHES(Text, '.*abc.*')
select Text from Library where Text LIKE '%abc%'
```

Here is the description of my table :

- SELECT count(*) from Library = 1 628 062
- SELECT AVG(LENGTH(Text)) from Library = 766 characters
- Library.script file is 2.5GB
- Text field is indexed
- I have already done a SHUTDOWN COMPACT;
- Library is an "in memory" table

Something that might not be normal :

- I do not have a Library.data or .data file for this DB

I am running out of ideas on what to do to make this kind of query faster.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Neither of those queries will be able to use an index (which is also true for almost all other DBMS except for Postgres). But a full scan on just 1.6 million rows shouldn't take 30seconds either. But I don't think there is anything you can do in HSQLDB to speed up those queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the query in its simplest form.

```
select text from library where position('abc' in text) > 0
```

I checked and this takes about a second on 1.5 million rows (but shorter average length). It should take less than the ones you tried.

Comment: Thanks fredt, it really is faster than like and regexp.
However, it is not as versatile as a like or a regexp.
Of course we can use position in a subquery as a first level filter and use regexp in the main query as a second level filter.
Do you see another way ?

Comment: No other way than you described. It may also work if you use POSITION(...) > 0 AND REGXP_MATCHES(...) as it normally applies the filters in the given order.

Comment: Yep, where POSITION('...' IN ...)>0 and REGEXP_MATCHES(..., '.*') gives the best performance and is probably the most elegant solution : ~ 1.5sec